# Two disk automorphisms are agree at a point of the open unit disk .

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the conjecture,

> If two disk automorphisms are agree at a point of the open unit disk,
>   then they must be identical.

I think this can be prove only using Schwartz lemma. Here is my attempt,
Let
$$φ_a (z)=\dfrac{z-a}{1-\overline{a} z}  ,a∈\mathbb{D}$$
Suppose $φ_a (z_0 )=φ_b (z_0 )$ for some $z_0∈\mathbb{D},$ where $a,b∈\mathbb{D}.$
Note that if $z_0=0$ or $z_0=a$ or $z_0=b,$ then the result is trivial.
Suppose $z_0≠0,a,b$  and define $f:\mathbb{C}→\mathbb{C}$ by,
$$f(z)=φ_{z_0} φ_{-a} φ_b φ_{-z_0}(z)  ,∀z∈\mathbb{C}$$
Then clearly $f:\mathbb{D}→\mathbb{D}$ and $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D}.$
Easily we can show that $f(0)=0.$
Therefore by the Schwartz lemma $$|f(z) |≤|z|  ,∀z∈\mathbb{D}$$
$$|φ_{z_0} φ_{-a} φ_b φ_{-z_0}(z)|≤|z|  ,∀z∈\mathbb{D}$$
Substituting $$z→φ_{z_0}φ_{-b} (z),$$ we can obtain, 
$$|φ_{z_0}φ_{-a} (z) )|≤|φ_{z_0}φ_{-b} (z)|.$$
Hence by the symmetry,
$$|φ_{z_0}φ_{-a} (z) )|=|φ_{z_0}φ_{-b} (z)|, \forall z\in\mathbb{D}.$$

After that I was stuck. How can I proceed from here?
Also I want to know other proofs for this conjecture.

Comment: There must be something missing. All rotations agree at $0$, but there is more than one rotation.

Comment: @DanielFischer: As you think what should be the additional condition? I think $ab\not=0$ would be enough. But I have no complete idea.

Comment: I don't know. If they also have the same derivative at $z_0$, that would suffice. But with only $\varphi(z_0) = \psi(z_0)$, the two can differ by a rotation about $\varphi(z_0)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: if I add the condition MONIC what can you say? I think this conjecture is true for any two monic disk automorphisms.

Comment: What does "monic" mean for a non-polynomial? It's likely that such a condition would fix the third degree of freedom you have in $\operatorname{Aut} (\mathbb{D})$, but without knowing what the condition means, I can't tell.

Comment: @DanielFischer: see [this](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwjx4KqOxorJAhXBjZQKHbZYDmg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fproc%2F1986-096-01%2FS0002-9939-1986-0813834-9%2FS0002-9939-1986-0813834-9.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEGCHhppdRGpExiuwmSyBY-x7RGOQ)

Comment: In that case, yes. It's the case $n = 1$ of the paper.

Comment: @DanielFischer: yes of course. But I am looking for a simpler proof of $n=1$ case. I strongly believe that  my approach is correct. But after that I am lost. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I find the proof in the paper quite simple. I couldn't think of a comparably simple way to prove it. Taking your ansatz, we know that $\varphi_a(\varphi_{-z_0}(cz)) \equiv \varphi_b(\varphi_{-z_0}(z))$ for all $z$, where $\lvert c\rvert = 1$. That is a bit more than you wrote down. But to deduce $a = b$ from that [and hence $c = 1$], I don't see a way to avoid tedious computations. Except considering $\varphi_a/\varphi_b$ as in the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjecture is false, as Daniel Fischer pointed out. Consider that the set of disk automorphisms 
$$
f(z)= e^{i\alpha}\frac{z-b}{1-\bar b z}
$$ 
is described by three real parameters: $\theta$, $\operatorname{Re}b$, $\operatorname{Im}b$.

When you require $f(z_0)=w_0$, that's two real equations. So there is a one-parameter family of automorphisms that satisfy it.

To pin down $f$, it suffices to prescribe $\arg f'(z_0)$ in addition to $f(z_0)$. An automorphism is prescribed by its value at a point and the argument of derivative at that point: this is true for [general simply-connected domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) and follows by applying the Schwarz lemma to an appropriate composition. (I.e., come up with a composition that is an automorphism of the disk that fixes the center and has positive derivative there. This must be the identity map.)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Still I did not completely understand your solution. I think, I need some time for that. If we narrow our attention only on monic disk automorphisms, is this conjecture become true?